# Problem with Instalation

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

I have two OSes (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04).

Yesterday I had an error:

```
Boot menu Sata CD :tsstcorp cddvdw sn-208bb
```

So I can no longer boot.

I decided to install Ubuntu from scratch again. I have it in a bootable USB.

When I was configuring the installation I had a new error:

> Please ensure that your computer has at least 6 GB free space for ubuntu

I tried to use GParted to make space - but all it found was the USB.

How can I use GParted to make space?

Comment: Your `scsi-dirve` is bricked. you may need to by a new disk.

Comment: @Tim bad experience om _my_ side :( . if `libparted` above 2.x does not list a drive it is bricked. you can build a house out of it. :)

Comment: @Tim this error means, that the bios was not able to find one as bootable marked hard drives. (try this: go to your bios menu and disable your disk with the bootloader)

Comment: @LittleByBlue I'm on an active web server atm, so really don't want to restart... Will check later, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you clicked the drop down?

[image]

By default GParted will show the current drive - which would have been USB in your case. I expect that your HDD will be in that dropdown.

If it isn't, open "Disks" and check that the disk is there, and is mounted.

Click it and ensure the icon is a Square (not a triangle)

[image]

If it is a triangle, click it and go back to GParted.

Comment: Ok I did not thought of ___this___

Comment: @LittleByBlue Common mistake I find - I've done it myself a few times (and gone as far as the other computer to fix a "missing" USB)!

Comment: :) nice! +1 for being close to real problems ;)

Comment: my hard disk doesn't didected

Answer (score -1):

you can use fdisk command manually for partition editing...
may be its a boot loader problem
to find partition name,use: cat /proc/partitions OR cat /etc/fstab
install GRUB again using live cd

grub-install /dev/sdx  (what ever ur drive is)
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
update-grub

Comment: now i m using just the trying version

Comment: fdisk is same as gparted,just not graphical...

Comment: i think the problem is in my hard disk, i think i must replace it